# Convert requests code to urllib in python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, urllib

I'm using `requests` module in my app but when i run it in google app engine, raise **SSL Connection** exception:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.385939809966824449/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 429, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

I google this problem and read some answers that said SSL module is not in *GAE while list*.
I can send a simple GET request with `urllib`. It was ok.
What is equivalent of `requests.request('GET', request_url, params=params, files=files)` in `urllib`?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
result = urllib2.urlopen(request_url, urllib.urlencode(params))
if result.getcode() == 200:
    pass #change it
```

but this code just can send text and numbers not files.